# Increase all Woocommerce products prices by a percentage

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am using Woocommerce in my website and I should need to add 24% extra to all my products prices.

How this can be done in an easy way?

Using a database Query will be the best way my be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could always write a query to do it directly in the database. Or if this is a temporary fix, you could consider making it a tax perhaps?

Comment: Yes query in database will be work for me. Can you give me something like this? Thanks for help

Comment: I haven't used WooCommerce for many years, so I cannot remember the database structure from memory. If you update your question, someone with more recent working knowledge might be able to help with that. Also, try writing a query yourself, but be sure to backup the database before running it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated** on July 2018 
You can run the following SQL query, that will update all your product prices adding **an extra 24%** *(and rounding prices too)*:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET `meta_value` = ROUND(`meta_value` * 1.24, 2) 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_price%' 
AND (meta_value > 0 or `meta_value` != '')
AND `post_id` IN (
    SELECT `ID` 
    FROM `wp_posts` 
    WHERE `post_type` = 'product' 
    AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
    AND `ID` = `post_id`
);
```

This is tested and works.

> Before running this SQL query **do a database backup**

You might need to **delete products transient cache** going to **Settings** `->` **Status** `->` **Tools** *(tab)* and in **"WooCommerce transients"** you will "**clear transients**";

---

**Handle product variations too:**

You just need to replace this line:

```
WHERE `post_type` = 'product'
```

By this line:

```
WHERE `post_type` IN ('product','product_variation')
```

Additionally you will also need to use:

```
DELETE
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE (`option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_%'
    OR `option_name` LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_%')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, This code add 24% but also add a "0" to offer price in all my products. Any suggestion  about that?

Comment: @Vachos I have updated my answer… it should work now without adding '0' to sale price (or empty prices).

Comment: Yes this dont add 0 but its add more than 24%. price from €3.95 result -> 5.53. thanks for help

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change `ROUND( meta_value * 1.40, 2)`  to `ROUND( meta_value * 1.24, 2)` …  I have updated my answer try it again… very sorry :)

Comment: Work perfect! Thanks man keep up the good work. best support i ever have in stackoverflow!

Comment: This doesnt work for variable products due to condition post_type='product'.I added " or post_type = 'product_variation' " to make it work.Thanks

Comment: I am pulling my hair out today I am stuck with a #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '' and I cannot figure out how to get past it

Comment: Thanks for this! It works. But with a little modification. I needed replace that line WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_price%'   with WHERE meta_key LIKE '%price%'